# Suppress iOS Two-Stage Animation warning

Tags: ios, warnings, rotation, suppress-warnings, autorotate

I'm doing two-stage animation on purpose, but I'm getting sick of seeing this warning in my logs.  How does one suppress this?

Edit: This is the warning I'm referring to: "Using two-stage rotation animation. To use the smoother single-stage animation, this application must remove two-stage method implementations."

Comment: Why do you need two-stage rotation animation?

Comment: I need to adjust placement of some subviews in response to the change in orientation and in my app it looks smoother to do this before the 2nd stage of the animation.